# Replace dates on a url which are saved on a list

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing, url

I have a list [ ] with dates, saved as strings (2020-12-01 to 2020-12-31). I also have the following url:

```
"https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/{date1:%Y-%m-%d}/{date1:%Y-%m-%d}/draw-id"
```

I want to run a "for loop" in which it will replaces the {date1:%Y-%m-%d} for every element (date) of the list. So far, I have created the following code which creates "ValueError: Invalid format specifier".

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import json, requests

def days_cur_month():
    d1 = date(2020, 12, 1)
    d2 = date(2020, 12, 31)
    delta = d2 - d1

    return [(d1 + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in range(delta.days + 1)]

print(days_cur_month())

fmt= "https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/{date1:%Y-%m-%d}/{date1:%Y-%m-%d}/draw-id"

draws=[]
for i in (days_cur_month()):
    
    url = fmt.format(date1=i)
    r=requests.get(url2)
    html=r.text
    drawIds=json.loads(html)
    print(drawIds)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` when using `str.format` with `conversion`

**Ex:**

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import json, requests

def days_cur_month():
    d1 = date(2020, 12, 1)
    d2 = date(2020, 12, 31)
    delta = d2 - d1

    return [(d1 + timedelta(days=i)) for i in range(delta.days + 1)]


fmt= "https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/{date1:%Y-%m-%d}/{date1:%Y-%m-%d}/draw-id"

draws=[]
for i in (days_cur_month()):
    url = fmt.format(date1=i)
    print(url)
```

**Output:**

```
https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/2020-12-27/2020-12-27/draw-id
https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/2020-12-28/2020-12-28/draw-id
https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/2020-12-29/2020-12-29/draw-id
https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/2020-12-30/2020-12-30/draw-id
https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/2020-12-31/2020-12-31/draw-id
```

---

Or if you need to use `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` Then change `fmt` to

```
fmt= "https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/{date1}/{date1}/draw-id"
```